# Simultaneous test for parameters with the marginaleffects package

Tags: r, r-marginaleffects

Is it possible to do a simultaneous F-test, likelihood ratio test or Wald test with the `marginaleffects::hypotheses` function? I'm looking for similar behavior as `car::linearHypothesis` and `multcomp:glht`. Minimal example:

```
library(multcomp)
library(car)

lmfit <- lm(mpg~as.factor(cyl)*hp, data=mtcars)
car::linearHypothesis(lmfit, c("as.factor(cyl)6:hp", "as.factor(cyl)8:hp"), test = "F")
car::linearHypothesis(lmfit, c("as.factor(cyl)6:hp", "as.factor(cyl)8:hp"), test = "Chisq")
summary(multcomp::glht(lmfit, c("`as.factor(cyl)6:hp` = 0", "`as.factor(cyl)8:hp` = 0")), test = Ftest())
summary(multcomp::glht(lmfit, c("`as.factor(cyl)6:hp` = 0", "`as.factor(cyl)8:hp` = 0")), test = Chisqtest())
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not currently possible with this function.

Comment: @Vincent: Thanks for the reply. Is it something you would consider implementing? Or is it out of the scope of your package?

Comment: I don't want to make too many promises about implementation or timeline, but I would certainly consider it. Feel free to open a feature request on Github, ideally with both a specific mathematical description of the quantity of interest and a reference software implementation.